# Sparql query doesn't upadate when insert some data through java code

Tags: java, sparql, jena, insert-update, fuseki

I'm trying to insert data through my java code to the owl file which is loaded into Fuseki server. Update query doesn't give any error message. But owl file doesn't update.I'm using jena library and implemented using java code. What is the wrong in my code?

```
    public boolean addLecturerTriples(String fName, String lName,
    String id, String module) {
    try{
    ArrayList<String> subject = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> predicate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> object = new ArrayList<String>();

    subject.add("<http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~csstnns/university.owl#"+fName+">");
    predicate.add("<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>");
    object.add("<http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~csstnns/university.owl#Lecturer>");

    for(int i = 0; i < subject.size(); i++){
        String qry = "INSERT DATA"+
                "{"+
                subject.get(i)+"\n"+
                predicate.get(i)+"\n"+
                object.get(i)+"\n"+
                "}";

        UpdateRequest update  = UpdateFactory.create(qry);
        UpdateProcessor qexec = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(update, "http://localhost:3030/ds/update");
        qexec.execute();
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: **I'm trying to insert data through my java code to the owl file which is loaded into Fuseki server. Update query doesn't give any error message. But owl file doesn't update.** What file should be updated?  If you insert data using Fuseki, it should be added the dataset, not to some external file (except, perhaps, a TDB dataset).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor dr I'm uploaded my owl file(which developed using protege ontology development tool) into fuseki server.I want to update that uploaded owl file.I'm trying to access that owl file using my java code.I want to insert data through my java code to that uploaded owl file.

Comment: That's not how (as far as I'm aware) Fuseki works.  Fuseki manages a dataset, which you can view as a collection of models.  When you "load your OWL file", what you're doing is reading the content of that file into a Fuseki model.  Aside from that, there's no connection between the Fuseki model and your OWL file.  I think you'd have to do something in code to grab the Fuseki model and overwrite your earlier file.

Comment: Just to make this a little bit clearer:  You could load the contents of a file into a Fuseki model, and then delete the file.  You'd still be able to query, insert, and delete with sparql queries and update requests.  Why does that work?  Because the in-memory model isn't connected to any file on disk.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thank you dr.I'm new to Fuseki and ontology.But previously I loaded my owl file to Fuseki server and select data.That worked fine.That's why I thought update query also will worked for insert data.

Comment: You can certainly `select` and `insert`;  it just doesn't have a connection to the file on disk.  `insert` modifies a graph in the dataset.  Using SPARQL updates you can create (and delete) graphs, and those wouldn't correspond to files on disk.  That said, I'm not all that familiar with Fuseki's implementation;  it may well be possible to add a hook or something that *would* write changes to a graph down to a corresponding file on disk.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Actually I'm not change any file on disk.I want to add new triples(insert) to my owl file. Before any changes normally I upload that file into Fuseki server and access that file through my java file.Actually I want to know how insert data into that file.I know how to select data from that file using Fuseki and Java code.But not known and my code doesn't work for insert.):

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that you're not changing a file on disk but that you want to insert new triples into your file.  Fuseki manages a *dataset* for you, and a dataset can have a number of *graphs* (with or without names).  From your last comment, it sounds like you're just trying to update the *graph* that Fuseki has, and that your `insert` request isn't working.  If it isn't working, how do you know?  Do you get an error message (if so, please show it in the question)?  Do you get no error message, but run a second query and you don't see the results (if so, what's the query)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you have provided a minimal complete example i.e. you had included your Fuseki configuration and the details of how your OWL file is loaded into Fuseki.

However I will assume you have not used any specific configuration and just launching Fuseki like so:

```
java -jar fuseki-server-VER.jar --update --loc /path/to/db /ds
```

So what you've done here is launch Fuseki with updates enabled and using the location `/path/to/db` as the on-disk TDB database location and the URL `/ds` for your dataset

The you open your browser and click through `Control Panel > /ds` and then use the Upload file function to upload your OWL file.  When you upload a file it is read into Fuseki and copied into the dataset, in this example your dataset is the on disk TDB database located at `/path/to/db`.

It is important to understand that **no reference to the original file is kept** since Fuseki has simply **copied** the data from the file to the dataset.

You then use the SPARQL Update form to add some data (or in your case you do this via Java code).  The update is applied to the dataset which to reiterate is in this example the on disk TDB database located at `/path/to/db` which has **no** reference to the original file.  Therefore your original file will not change.

### Using SPARQL Update to update the original file

If Fuseki is not essential then you could just load your file into local memory and run the update there instead:

```
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
m.read("example.owl", "RDF/XML");

// Prepare your update...

// Create an UpdateExecution on the local model
UpdateProcessor processor = UpdateExecutionFactory.create(update, GraphStoreFactory.create(m));
processor.execute();

// Save the updated model 
updated.write(new FileOutputStream("example.owl"), "RDF/XML");
```

However if you want to/must stick with using Fuseki you can update your original file by retrieving the modified graph from Fuseki and writing it back out to your file e.g.

```
DatasetAccessor accessor = DatasetAccessorFactory.createHTTP("http://localhost:3030/ds/data");

// Download the updated model
Model updated = accessor.getModel();

// Save the updated model over the original file
updated.write(new FileOutputStream("example.owl"), "RDF/XML");
```

This example assumes that you have loaded the OWL file into the default graph, if not use the `getModel("http://graph")` overload to load the relevant named graph

Comment: Thank you soo much @RobV .That's work fine.My most of problems solved.Thank you soo much..Have a nice day. :)