# how to insert data in to rdf file using jena and Sparql query

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I try to insert data into rdf file using jena and sparql query.But it gives com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException. i want to insert ""\user" and his details to rdf file using java.I can write data in rdf file using file writer but i think it is not a best way to insert data in to rdf file.I try to do that using below answer 
-[Sparql query doesn't upadate when insert some data through java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894571/sparql-query-doesnt-upadate-when-insert-some-data-through-java-code) 

but it is not working properly.I can't find the mistake i did here.

```
public class insertdata {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new insertdata().addLecturerTriples("user5");
    }

    public boolean addLecturerTriples(String user) {

        try {
            Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
            m.read("/Users/heshanjayasinghe/Documents/A-enigmaProject/jena_Enigma/src/jena_enigma/Enigma.RDF", "RDF/XML");

            ArrayList<String> subject = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> predicate = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> object = new ArrayList<String>();

            //  subject.add("<http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~csstnns/university.owl#"+fName+">");
            subject.add("http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#" + user + ">");
            //  predicate.add("<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>");
            predicate.add("http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#type");
            //  object.add("<http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~csstnns/university.owl#Lecturer>");
            object.add("http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#User");

            for (int i = 0; i < subject.size(); i++) {
                String qry = "INSERT DATA"
                        + "{"
                        + subject.get(i) + "\n"
                        + predicate.get(i) + "\n"
                        + object.get(i) + "\n"
                        + "}";

                UpdateRequest update = UpdateFactory.create(qry);
                UpdateProcessor processor = UpdateExecutionFactory.create(update, GraphStoreFactory.create(m));
                processor.execute();
          //      UpdateProcessor qexec = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(update, "http://localhost:3030/ds/update");
// Save the updated model 
                m.write(new FileOutputStream("/Users/heshanjayasinghe/Documents/A-enigmaProject/jena_Enigma/src/jena_enigma/Enigma.RDF"), "RDF/XML");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

rdf file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY Enigma "http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#"
     xml:base="http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:Enigma="http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Object Properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#AskQuestion -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&Enigma;AskQuestion"/>



    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#type -->

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&Enigma;type">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Data properties
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#email -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&Enigma;email">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#fname -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&Enigma;fname">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;Name"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#lname -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&Enigma;lname">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;Name"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#password -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&Enigma;password">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#uname -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&Enigma;uname">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
    </owl:DatatypeProperty>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#Question -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&Enigma;Question"/>



    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#User -->

    <owl:Class rdf:about="&Enigma;User"/>



    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Individuals
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->




    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#Question1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Enigma;Question1"/>



    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#User1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Enigma;User1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
        <password rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">hesh</password>
        <fname rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">heshan</fname>
        <email rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">heshjay@hotmail.com</email>
        <lname rdf:datatype="&xsd;Name">jayasinghe</lname>
        <AskQuestion rdf:resource="&Enigma;Question1"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#User2 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Enigma;User2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
        <password rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">123</password>
        <fname rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">hesh</fname>
        <email rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">heshjse@gmail.com</email>
        <lname rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">jay</lname>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.heshjayasinghe.webatu.com/Enigma.RDF#user3 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&Enigma;user3">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
        <password rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">123</password>
        <fname rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">hesh</fname>
        <email rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">hhh@gmail.com</email>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>



<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 3.4.2) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net -->
```

Comment: Print the string 'qry' and check it for parse errors.  The error message from the parser has the line and column number of the first error.

Comment: thanks i found that error now i can add user into  my rdf do you know how to add user details into rdf? e.g.:<rdf:type rdf:resource="&Enigma;User"/>
        <password rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">hesh</password>
        <fname rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">heshan</fname>
        <email rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">heshjay@hotmail.com</email>
        <lname rdf:datatype="&xsd;Name">jayasinghe</lname>
        <AskQuestion rdf:resource="&Enigma;Question1"/>