# Convert OWLAxiom to Jena Model

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology

I need to convert simple OWLAxiom to Jena Model in Java. 
I already get answer how to convert OWLOntology to Jena Model

[Conversion from OWLOntology to Jena Model in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866783/conversion-from-owlontology-to-jena-model-in-java)

, that's working, but I need to create similar model from simple OWLAxiom, not OWLOntology. So is there some way how to do that? Or is it possible to parse Jena Model and divide it to more Models accroding to axioms?

Maybe there is a solution to convert OWLAxiom to String, but I don't know if that is the best solution for my problem. If it is, I tried something like this, but it doesnt seem to work :

```
public static Model convertAxiomToModel(OWLAxiom axiom) throws IOException {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        String stringAxiom = axiom.toString();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stringAxiom.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));
        model.read(in, null, "TURTLE");

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: You have to put the axiom into an ontology object and then do the same as provided in your link.

Comment: @AKSW thanks, it's working