# SPARQL Jena - functional-style syntax

Tags: sparql, jena, owl-api

Is it possible to read OWL ontology written in functional-style syntax in SPARQL Jena? The Api seems to read only RDF/XML files correctly:

```
model.read(SOURCE,"RDF/XML");
```

If no, are there other alternatives for dealing with SPARQL in Java? I'm using OWL API and HermiT reasoner for the rest of the code. The other api needs to be compatible with OWL API and HermiT.

Comment: Short answer, no: all languages are listed in the [docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-input.html)

Comment: Solution: use OWL API to serialize it as `RDF/XML` and use this as input for Jena. You can directly pipe the outputstream to an inputstream in Java, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866783/conversion-from-owlontology-to-jena-model-in-java)

Comment: Are there better apis which allow to do that without additional translation? The operation is time consuming

Comment: I'm only aware of Apache Jena and RDF4J for SPARQL in Java. Maybe [owllet](https://github.com/phenoscape/owlet) is something related to your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/wiki/Examples#ex5), which is OWL-API+Jena, allows read models in Functional syntax